# Skype Wayland versus Xorg black screen at startup

Tags: xorg, skype, wayland

Ubuntu 23.04 when under Wayland the Skype screen is black. It takes up to or more then 60 seconds before the black window in skype turns normal. under Xorg the screen is visible immediately. Have this issue somewhere since Ubuntu 21.10 or so. Anyone else has this ? All the same on Ubuntu 23.04 using kernels 6.2, 6.3, 6.4 and 6.5rc1.

Comment: This is still happening on Ubuntu 23.04. using using the X.org driver. NVIDIA drivers don't work on this GEFORCE GT610 Video card in Ubuntu 23.04. Yes an old video card but this 12 year old PC is working still very well...